# Robustly sending emails through Outlook and OLE

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

I'm using OLE to send email through Outlook.  The code I am using is:

```
procedure SendOutlookMail;
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  OKToUse: boolean;
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  vMailItem: variant;
begin
  OKToUse := false;
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    OKToUse := true;
  except
    try
      Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
      OKToUse := true;
    except
      on e: exception do begin
        ShowMessage(e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if VarIsType(Outlook, varDispatch) then
    ShowMessage('Outlook is varDispatch')
  else
    ShowMessage('Outlook is ***NOT*** varDispatch');

  if OKToUse then begin
    vMailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
    vMailItem.Recipients.Add('mike@example.com');
    vMailItem.Subject := 'What a wonderful test email';
    vMailItem.Body := 'This is a test --> how amazing';
    vMailItem.Send;
  end;

  VarClear(Outlook);
end;
```

Which has been unashamedly nicked from a couple of different SO questions - thanks to all.

The problem I have with the code is when Outlook is installed on the PC, but is closed. When Outlook is open I get a message box saying "Outlook is varDispatch" and a mail message is send and received.  When Outlook is closed I get the same message box "Outlook is varDispatch", but then "An error occurred in the application" and my application closes abruptly.

So two questions:

1)  How do I detect if Outlook is running?  The fact that OKToUse gets set to true seems to not be the right way.

2)  How do I start Outlook if it isn't running and close it after an email has been sent?

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and trying to connect to Outlook 2007.

Comment: If `GetActiveOleObject()` succeeds, it is obviously open. Set another `Boolean` that indicates this. Otherwise, make it  `False`. If you must use `CreateOleObject()`, it must be opened, and that seems to fail. Do you perhaps have to set some properties first, before you can use it?

Comment: Why don't you use COM server wrapper component?

Comment: A down vote?  For what?  This place is too tough sometimes :(

Comment: Thank you, @RudyVelthuis I don't know about setting other properties - they are not mentioned in places where I've found the code. I take your point about the second boolean.

Comment: Thank you @FreeConsulting.  When searching for how to send emails via Outlook, this method pops up regularly, so I chose it.  What advantages does the COM wrapper component offer?

Comment: @MichaelVincent Early binding (I wanted to add a wikipedia link, but there it's called [Static binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_dispatch) strangely enough), finding the properties/methods over an OleVariant is slow(er).

Comment: @StijnSanders - thanks for your comment, but how does it help with my question?  Regards,

Comment: @MichaelVincent It was in response to the question "What advantages does the COM wrapper component offer?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following before calling CreateItem

```
vNS := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
vNS.Logon;
```